# Rolling back transactions after exception is thrown

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

When I throw exception in service method I expected that transactional annotation on service will rollback save operation, but it is not working.

This is my service:

```
  @Service
  @Transactional(value = "transactionManager", rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public class OrderServiceImp implements OrderService {
        @Autowired
        private OrderRepository orderRepository;

        @Override
        public void doSomeStaff(Long orderId) {
             Order order = orderRepository.findOne(orderId);
             orderRepository.save(order);
             throw new NullPointerException("Test transaction exeption");
        }
    }
```

In data.xml I have next configs:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>


<jpa:repositories base-package="com.dmitro.repositories" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>
```

In dispatcher-servlet.xml I declared scan:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.dmitro.service" />
```

I am using spring-data-jpa 1.8.0.RELEASE. Please help!

Comment: Please post the rest of your spring config.  How is your Service being register?

Comment: Updated info about what and where located in my configs.

Comment: Is data.xml imported in the dispatcher-servlet.xml?  Is OrderServiceImp in the com.dmitro.service package?

Comment: Why do you have two transaction managers?

Comment: Spring will rollback the transaction opened for the service. But since the DAO uses a different transaction manager, the transaction opened for the DAO has already been committed at this time. Steve Hall's question is the right one: why do you have two transaction managers?

Comment: About two transaction managers: I removed one, now I am using one  transaction manager but still have the same

Comment: Please post ALL your Spring config.

Comment: You direction was right, because it was a configuration problem, thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in configuration, because I declared services and transaction manager in different spring contexts: transaction manager was in root context and services was in child dispatcher-servlet.xml context.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Transactional(value = "transactionManagerForServiceLayer", rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

This is the culprit. You should not have different transaction manager for service and repository. To fix it, you need to replace transactionManagerForServiceLayer here to transactionManager and then rollback will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to throw the Exception in OrderRepositoryImpl to see if it works

```
public class OrderRepositoryImpl implements OrderRepository {
    @Override
    public void save() {
        throw new SomeRunTimeException();
    }
}

public class OrderServiceImp implements OrderService {
    @Override
    public void doSomeStaff(Long orderId) {
        Order order = orderRepository.findOne(orderId);
        orderRepository.save(order);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The DataSource AutoCommit is ON (or True).  Turn it OFF (or false).